# 'Failed to fetch' error when downloading files that has more than 10mb React + Spring boot

Tags: reactjs, https, download, blob, multipartform-data

Have a client-side server in react that need to request files from backend server (kotlin + spring boot) to download them.

Using the request endpoint in Swagger, Postman and Insomnia, i can success download any file with any size.

In my client-side server, have a list of this files that download can be triggered by a click in an icon. I can download files that has less than 10mb with no error, but when file has more than 10mb, it fails with `Failed to fetch` error.

Actually, it's a weird behavior. Let say i have a file named `FILE A` that has under than 10mb and `FILE B` with 25MB (is the max size allowed to upload). In first entried of the page, if i first request to download FILE B, it throw `Failed to fetch`. Now, if first request is in FILE A and after FILE B, FILE B download is successed. I'm really confused what is going on here.

Code:

```
 const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${user?.token}` },
};
fetch(`http://localhost:8080/storage/download?fileName=${filePath}`, options)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.blob();
  })
  .then(function (myBlob) {
    setSpinControl(false);

    const file = new Blob(
      [myBlob],
      { type: 'application/pdf' }
    );

    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    if (window) {
      window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    setSpinControl(false);
    console.log(err)
  });
```

Already tried some alternatives:

- Using axios (throw `Network Error`);
- Using libraries as file-saver;
- Setting timeout to 9999999;

All achieve same behavior.

I read too that createObjectURL uses memory to perform download, but max size of a file is validated to be 25MB.

Some print of Network tab:

**Request Header:**
[image: requestHeader]

**Request Response:**
[image: requestResponse]

**Network List:**
[image: network]

Any tips what i can do here?

Answer (score 0):

Please check and **increase the timeout in React**, i had the same problem.